# Need help in task of panda dataframe (juypternotebook) HELP NEW problem "Only the most traded stock of the firm"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Hi guys i started at jupyter notebook few days ago.

I need help, i have a dataframe by panda. something like this

```
Date    Stock   Company   Volume

01/02    APPL3   Apple     1.000.000

01/02    YUSS    Yusduqs     200.000

01/02    APPL4    Apple      200.000

01/02    DISN    Disney      1.500.000

02/02    APPL3    Apple       100.000

02/02    YUSS    Yusduqs     1.250.000

02/02    DISN     Disney     2.000.000

02/02    APPL4    Apple     1.250.000

 ...            ...           ....
```

I need to select the stock that was traded in more than 80% of the days with volume greater than $ 500.000,00 per day.

And i need to select **only one stock per firm, the criterio is which has more volume in all days combined. Like for 'Apple' in [Company] i have two diferents [Stock] Appl3 and Appl4, in this specific case i only need APPL4.

(Because Volume of the days combined in Appl4 > Volume of the days combined in Appl3)

I started like this:

`unique_dates=len(df['Date'].value_counts()) 
share_freq=df[df['Volume']>=500000]]['Stock'].value_counts() stocks=share_freq/unique_dates for stock,value in stocks.items(): 
      if(value>0.8): 
          print(stock)`

So after that i can see which one has>0.8 but i still need to select only one stock per firm. I dont know how to respect all the criterios and by the end filter all the dataframe by the criterios and save in .csv

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know the proper code for it but at a high-level, you will, first of all, need to check which stocks were traded in 80% of the days and then check which one of those was traded above 500,000.

Comment: Thank u for the comment @FabioRamos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know the frequency of stocks which traded greater than 500000 for 80% of days by,

```
unique_dates=len(df['Date'].value_counts())
share_freq=df[df['Volume']>=500000]]['Stock'].value_counts()
stocks=share_freq/unique_dates
for stock,value in stocks.items():
    if(value>0.8):
        print(stock)
```

Answer to extended question..

```
stock_dict=dict()
for stock,value in stocks.items():
    if(value>0.8):
        stock_df=df[df['Stock']==stock]
        volume=stock_df['Volume'].sum()
        key=stock_df['Company']
        key=key.iloc[0]
        try:
            if(volume> stock_dict[key][1]):
                stock_dict[key]=(stock,volume)
        except:
            stock_dict[key]=(stock,volume)
print(stock_dict)
```

Here after we find the stock that occur in 80% of the dates and volume greater than 500000. I have made a dictionary which stores the maximum volume of stocks of a company. printing stock_dict gives the tuple stock with maximum volume in the company and its volume.

Comment: Thanks Sudheer , that was really helpful. But if u let me ask something more, i recently add a new problem on the question.

Comment: I didn't understand the extended question. We will given the company and we need to find the most traded stock right? And most traded means which recorded the maximum volume or most traded means which has the highest sum of volumes in all the days combined?

Comment: `unique_dates=len(df['Date'].value_counts())
share_freq=df[df['Volume']>=500000]]['Stock'].value_counts()
stocks=share_freq/unique_dates
for stock,value in stocks.items():
    if(value>0.8):
        print(stock)`

So after that i can see which one has>0.8
but i still need to select only one stock per firm, like in the case above, i need APPL4*
(for apple i have two different stock appl4 and appl3 but i don't need appl3 because it has a lower volume then appl3)


I dont know how to respect all the criterios
and by the end filter all the dataframe by the criterios and save in .csv

Comment: I have updated the answer, check whether it helps or not